# fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/master...HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree in Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure-devops

I want to check the formatting of **modified** Python files in Azure DevOps. I'm only using `git branch -a` to see what's going on. I don't have permissions to use `git fetch`.

Currently running this:

```
jobs:
  - job: Linting
    displayName: Format code
    steps:
      - task: UsePythonVersion@0
        inputs:
          versionSpec: 3.x

      - script: |
          pip install black
        displayName: 'Install Black'

      - script: |
          git branch -a
          git diff --name-only origin/master...HEAD --diff-filter=AM | grep '\.py$' | xargs black --check 
        displayName: 'Format files'
```

Which gives me this error:

```
* (HEAD detached at origin/11111111111xxxxxx)
  remotes/origin/11111111111xxxxxx
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/master...HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

I branched directly off of master for my changes. I don't have any issues running this locally.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you working on a shallow clone? Or cloned specifying the branch you wanted to clone?

Comment: I cloned master.

Comment: This part of the output does not make sense if you only cloned `master`:  `HEAD detached at origin/11111111111xxxxxx`. What is `origin/11111111111xxxxxx`? Looks like a reference to me.

Comment: What command are you using for cloning there?

Comment: I used git clone https://something-vsts@dev.azure.com/something-vsts/something/_git/something-repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run `git diff`, disable shallow fetch on checkout:

- [Shallow fetch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-checkout?view=azure-pipelines#shallow-fetch)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/pipeline-options-for-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#shallow-fetch

---

```
  jobs: 
  - job: A
      steps:
      - checkout: self
        fetchDepth: 0
```